# Error using BeginTransaction in csharp-sqlite .Net library

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8

I am using csharp-sqlite library.

The code:

```
var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DatabasePath);
conn.Execute("insert or replace into Option(Key, Value) values ('A', '1')");
conn.Execute("insert or replace into Option(Key, Value) values ('B', '2')");
```

It works as I expect. However when I use BeginTransaction() and Commit, I get an exception in the second Excute: "CannotOpen", the native is SQLITE_CANTOPEN (error 14).

The code would be:

```
var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DatabasePath);
try
{
  conn.BeginTransaction();
  conn.Execute("insert or replace into Option(Key, Value) values ('A', '1')");
  conn.Execute("insert or replace into Option(Key, Value) values ('B', '2')");
  conn.Commit();
}
catch (SQLiteException ex)
{
     _conn.Rollback();

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this problem when running on WinRT.

This pragma fix the issue :

```
using(var connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
{
   connection.Execute(string.Format("PRAGMA temp_store_directory = '{0}';", Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path));
}
```

See
http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Transaction-issues-with-WinRT-build-td63817.html

Answer (score 2):

From the examples I see, though they are not all using CSharp-Sqlite, you should use it like this:

```
using(var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DatabasePath)) 
{
  conn.Open();
  using(var tr = conn.BeginTransaction())
  {
    try
    {
      using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
      {
        cmd.Transaction = tr;
        cmd.CommandText = @"insert or replace into Option(Key, Value) 
                              values ('A', '1')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.CommandText = @"insert or replace into Option(Key, Value) 
                              values ('B', '2')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      tr.Commit();
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
      tr.Rollback();
    }
  }
  conn.Close();
}
```

[This is one of those examples](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitecsharp/trans/).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use SQLite for WinRT (rather than the default SQLite package) and the SQLite async wrapper in sqlite-net. The File IO interface has changed in Windows 8, so you get an exception when native DLLs try to use them.

See here for a walkthrough of how to use the async wrapper:
http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2012/10/windows-8-using-sqlite-in-your-windows-store-application/